# How to open webpage with specific div using Respose.Redirect()?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, response.redirect

I want to open one webpage of asp.net with specific div

just like

```
<a id="url" href="mypage.aspx#tab1">Home</a>
```

I want to do this using

```
Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");
```

Comment: hope you tried Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx#tab1");

Comment: There is no such thing as "urgent question" on Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Yes it is not working....thats why i am asking.

Comment: @ abatishchev yeah i know but i mention it because really i want it on urgent basis.

Comment: @user1969130, as abatishchev already told you there's no such notion as urgency on StackOverflow. If you need something urgently and do not know how to do it you always have the possibility to hire a web developer do the job for you. Here depending on the quality of your question and the amount of efforts you have already put into solving the problem you will get an answer sooner or later or never.

Comment: @abatishchev @ Darin Dimitrov  Ok Thanks. :-)

Comment: "Yes it is not working" - is very bad explanation of your problem. I.e. in web case you need to explain what kind of HTTP response you are getting and what kind of response/request/url you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a `<div>` exists client side. With a redirect you can only say that the current request should be submitted again at the new address. You can't specify where that redirect should end (frame, iframe, div, window ..).

You will have to do it from the client side: have the div (or whatever) load from some url (which could do a redirect).

Or inside of `mypage.aspx` page do this JQuery to animate and move to specific div

```
$(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#header1").offset().top });
});
```